# Python Outlook inbox saving attachments win32com.client

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I have gotten some of the features I want but need help with 2 others.

1. I would like to flag the message "Mark as Done" (it's one of the Flag statuses). I have not found how to do this.
2. If I wanted to do this same thing for 4 other emails how would I do it, with 4 other save paths?

```
import win32com.client
import os
Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inboxfolder = Outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case the inbox. You can change that number to reference
inbox = inboxfolder.Items
message = inbox.GetFirst()
subject = message.Subject
sender = message.SenderEmailAddress

for m in inbox:
    if m.Class == 43: # this is to make sure it is an email item and not something else. 
        if m.SenderEmailAddress == 'John@email.com' and m.Unread == True:
            path = 'C:\\User\\Path\\Data\\John'
            print ('Subject as: ' and message)
            for attached in message.Attachments:
                attached.SaveASFile(os.path.join(path,attached.FileName)) #Saves attachment to current folder
                print (attached)
            message.Unread = False
            print (message.FlagStatus)
            message.FlagStatus = 1  # This is to "mark as Done" but it doesn't work
            message = inbox.GetNext()
        elif m.SenderEmailAddress == 'Jane@email.com' and m.Unread == True:
            path = 'C:\\User\\Path\\Data\\Jane'

            # ... How would you add 4 more? 
            message = inbox.GetNext()
        else:
            message = inbox.GetNext()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You have to save it `message.Save()`, Example*

```
import win32com.client
Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
olNs = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(win32com.client.constants.olFolderInbox)

for Item in Inbox.Items:
    if Item.Class == 43:
        Item.FlagStatus = 1
        Item.Save()
```

---

*For multiple emails & path use [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3294899/4539709), Example*

```
emails_with_path = {
    "email@one.com": "path_one",
    "email@two.com": "path_two",
    "email@three.com": "path_three"
}

for m in inbox:
    if m.Class == 43:
        for email, path in emails_with_path.items():
            if m.SenderEmailAddress == email and m.UnRead:
                print(email)
                print(path)
```